# Avoiding many similar IDs for similar text entry boxes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, code-duplication

In a demo site I have four text boxes which are grouped into two pairs of two (two dimensions, each dimension has two sets). I use only IDs and a naming scheme to get javascript to read each one individually. Is there a cleaner way of using element selectors to avoid having so many similarly named IDs and duplicated code? Can CSS selectors be used for this purpose?

Example HTML

```
    <form id="user-dimension-form" action="javascript:processDimensionInput();plotScatter()" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="user-dimension-area">
            <label>Dimension 1 Name
                <!-- TODO: better naming scheme in CSS -->
                <input class="user-dimension-name" id="user-dimension-feature1-name-input" type="text">
            </label>

            <div class="user-dimension-entry">
                <textarea class="user-dimension-feature-set" id="user-dimension-feature1-set1" rows="16"></textarea>
                <textarea class="user-dimension-feature-set" id="user-dimension-feature1-set2" rows="16"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="user-dimension-area">
            <label>Dimension 2 Name
                <input class="user-dimension-name" id="user-dimension-feature2-name-input" type="text">
            </label>
            <div class="user-dimension-entry">
                <textarea class="user-dimension-feature-set" id="user-dimension-feature2-set1" rows="16"></textarea>
                <textarea class="user-dimension-feature-set" id="user-dimension-feature2-set2" rows="16"></textarea>
            </div>


        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

        <span id="user-dimension-message"></span>

    </form>
```

Example javascript reading the textareas showing the duplicated code. Should I avoid manually concat together HTML ID strings?

```js
    const feature1Set1Input = parseInput("user-dimension-feature1-set1");
    const feature1Set2Input = parseInput("user-dimension-feature1-set2");
    const feature2Set1Input = parseInput("user-dimension-feature2-set1");
    const feature2Set2Input = parseInput("user-dimension-feature2-set2");
```

Comment: Naming schemes are generally personal. Sure you need to follow a certain naming conventions, but its really just boils down to general creativity. You could have them all end in a number and iterate over them using js. But even then, the data you need to manage is likely unique and so what you can do after selecting them using iterations would still be quite limited.

Comment: I should clarify this question is not really about naming schemes - more about how to select the elements without using so many similar sounding names.

Comment: I gathered as much, but that is still about how to name something more effectively. You gotta dig into your creativity friend!

Comment: I though possibly about using CSS selectors, but I don't know if this is good practice to use them this way.

Comment: I have never tried it, but that doesn't mean it shouldnt be done.

Answer (score 1):

Given the above html, I suppose you could do something like the following:

```
let form = document.getElementById('user-dimension-form');
let inputs = form.querySelectorAll('textarea');
let values = [];
inputs.forEach( input => values.push(input.value) );
```

Not sure that I would though. Can't see any benefit.

Comment: interesting approach, but loses the structure of the two pairs along the way

Comment: @qwr - no and yes. You've got named variables, I've got consecutive array indices. Many elements in an array can be processed with little code. Contrast that to having to type out the name of each input. ;)

Comment: yeah that's true. maybe I can use a two-deep nested array to represent the structure

Answer (score 0):

The method I came up with is to use CSS selectors. So each input is named has class something like `"user-feature-words feature0 set0"` and it is selected by something like

```
document.querySelector(`.user-feature-words.feature${i}.set${j}`)
```

Of course since I'm combining CSS selectors, I could've used the same string to get a unique ID.